# How to filter all points which are before a given 3d (general) plane in pcl

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm using pcl to process point cloud data. I want to filter all points which are before a given 3d plane, this plane is defined by `pcl::ModelCoefficients` (ax + by + cz + d = 0).

Here is the case: when a given plane is placed into point cloud, then surely the cloud will be separated into two parts - before and behind this given 3d plane. There are two similar methods, one is `pcl::PassThrough`, the other one is `pcl::ConditionalRemoval`, but I don't know if they can realize my goal?

My question is how to extract all points before that plane? If there is one or more methods, then which one is the effective way?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I figure out one way to do it, but I doubt if it's a effective way.

```cpp
pcl::ModelCoefficients plane; // given (a,b,c,d) of ax + by + cz + d = 0

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
for(int i = 0; i < source_point_cloud->points.size(); i++)
{
  PointXYZ point = source_point_cloud->points[i];

  if(point.x * plane.values[0] + point.y * plane.values[1] + point.z *  plane.values[2] +  plane.values[3] > 0)
  {
    filtered->points.push_back(point);
  }
}
```

Theory is point(x,y,z) on the plane will make formula satisfied:

**a * x + b * y + c * z + d = 0;**

If a point is before('before the plane' is not clearly defined, but you know what I mean) this plane then we get a inequality:

**a * x + b * y + c * z + d > 0;**

Otherwise, points are behind the plane.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Looking in the doc, I found a function called "PlaneClipper3D" that might solve it for future users.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>::Ptr filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>);
Eigen::Vector4f plane_parameters{a,b,c,d};
pcl::PlaneClipper3D<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal> clipper(plane_parameters);
pcl::Indices filterIndices;
clipper.clipPointCloud3D(*cloud_to_filter, filterIndices);

//Copy point with good indices
pcl::copyPointCloud(*cloud_to_filter, filterIndices, *filtered);
```

https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_plane_clipper3_d.html#ab9550462630a027be9fb42fc250766ab

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32300327)

Comment: Edited the answer to display how I did it in my case